# How to return related value from database after click function by ajax in django?

Tags: python, django, ajax

html

```
  <div>           
  
 {{ productform.vendorid|as_crispy_field }}<a id="vendor_id_search" class="btn btn-info">search</a></br>
    
    <div style="display:none;" id="show_vendorname">hjkh</div><br>
 </div>
 


 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>




 <script>
$("#vendor_id_search").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var vendor_id = $("#id_vendorid").val();

  $.ajax({
    url: '/ajax/find_vendorname/',
    method: 'GET',
    data: {
      'vendor_id': vendor_id
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        $("#show_vendorname").show(data)
    }
  });

});
```

views.py

```
 #vendor_name_find_ajax
 def find_vendorname(request):
     if request.is_ajax():
         vendorid = request.GET.get('vendor_id', None)
         username = CustomUser.objects.filter(first_name=vendorid)
         return username
```

I want to display the related name from the database table for that vendorid after the user typed the vendorid field and once clicked the button, the related name should be displayed on that particular div. Here, I have made a mistake and don't know to get that value.

Comment: You need to find the part where you are stuck. 1. Is your ajax request sent?(check in browsers network tab ) 2. Is your views.py function called and does find something/send something back to the browser. 3. is your js correct, does it get the data and do you correctly insert it into html.... Check with print() and console.log() where you are stuck. My guess is at views.py return username will fail since its a queryset not a HttpResponse. you need to render it properly. Maybe use something like DRF (just a tip)

Comment: I understand the whole concept of this method and I checked by your reference. It was an error with sending ajax request. By the way thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$("#show_vendorname").show(data)` unhide the div, but don't set in the data.

You need set the data before with `$.html()`

```js
$("#show_vendorname").html(data).show()
```

**EDIT:**

Besides, your view needs to return a `HttpResponse`:

```py
from django.http import HttpResponse

def find_vendorname(request):
     if request.is_ajax():
         vendorid = request.GET.get('vendor_id', None)
         username = CustomUser.objects.filter(first_name=vendorid)
         return HttpResponse(username)
```

Comment: but didn't get output. is that the view function and ajax function is correct for my requirement?

Comment: Sorry @sam. I edited the response.

Comment: Thank you, I got the point. thanks for your answer.